# Python - Plot data from a file

Tags: python, plot, data-files

I have a large file with data stored in columns like that:

```
Pression Volume Temperature
2 3 6
4 2 8
5 3 15
```

I would like to plot together the values from different columns to compare them with the values from an other given column. For example, the pression and the volume in y-axis and the temperature in x-axis.

In my example, it could give something like that:

[image]

Where the pression is in blue, the volume in red and the temperature in x-axis.

How can I do it ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The values are space separated and the file is a .dat file

I can't get each value by hand, my real file is quite large for it

Comment: Is the file a tab or space separated value file? Hard to see in your example.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried something by reading the file in lines, but I can't get the values from a given column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pressure': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 5}, 'Volume': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'Temperature': {0: 6, 1: 8, 2: 15}})

df.plot(x= 'Temperature', y=['Pressure', 'Volume'], marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In response to you comment, if you have a csv file called 'sample.csv' that looks like this:

```
Pressure,Volume,Temperature
2,3,6
4,2,8
5,3,15
```

You can create the dataframe and plot it as shown below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df.plot(x= 'Temperature', y=['Pressure', 'Volume'], marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but it is not what I am looking for, because you got by hand the values. I would like to get all the values from a column in a list for example with a while loop or something better I hope then plot them

Comment: You don't need a for loop.  Provide a sample of your data (e.g. in a list or csv file) and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: @Julien See my amended answer about how to turn your csv data file into a dataframe and the plot it.

Comment: It returns " KeyError: 'pression' "  I checked the spelling. Maybe it comes from the read_csv: I have a file.dat and I can't get a csv...

Comment: You need to convert your dat file to csv.  Check this out: https://anyconv.com/dat-to-csv-converter/

Comment: I can't convert it to a csv file, there is an error. I tried to take an other csv file but I still have the same key error with the csv file...

Comment: Notice that in my code, I have called it 'Pressure' not 'pression.'

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, and I took the same column name (copy past), after I tried to add a space but still nothing

Comment: Also, I tried to show df and I have the table, so the data are imported in a good way

Comment: Print your df and post a screen shot of its first few rows.

Comment: Ok, I fixed this error by doing: df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=' ')

Comment: I think it works, I have a graphic. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  That was a lot of work.  Make sure you accept the answer, not just upvote it.